# How to extract elements of a vector of strings in Rust?

Tags: vector, rust, ownership

Let's say I have the following [code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=699e45494bb6578f5ca9ee10cae4117b):

```
fn extract() -> Vec<String> {
    let data = vec!["aaa".to_string(), "bbb".to_string(), "ccc".to_string()];
    vec![data[0], data[2]]
}
```

In practice, I read `data` from a file.

Obviously, this doesn't compile because I'm pulling strings out of the vector `data`, leaving the vector in an undefined state. But, conceptually, it should work, because I'm not using `data` afterwards anyway.

I can use `mem::replace`, but this seems crazy:

```
fn extract() -> Vec<String> {
    let mut data = vec!["aaa".to_string(), "bbb".to_string(), "ccc".to_string()];
    let a = mem::replace(&mut data[0], "".to_string());
    let c = mem::replace(&mut data[2], "".to_string());
    vec![a, c]
}
```

How do I go about extracting specific elements from the vector without having to clone the strings?

Comment: "But, conceptually, it should work, because I'm not using data afterwards anyway." and how drop from Vec will know to drop only the string you didn't remove ?

Comment: @Stargateur It doesn't know, which is why it doesn't compile. But, undefined data only matters if it is used, and it is not used in my example, which is why a smarter compiler should see this code as valid.

Comment: You didn't undertand, String HAVE a drop implementation, as Vec isn't a compiler internal, it can't have this level of understanding. That doesn't matter that you don't use the data the compiler still need to call drop implementation. And it do that on Vec, and Vec will call drop on all its element, Vec have no way to know that you move two values

Comment: @Stargateur You are speaking for the current compiler implementation, which has all sorts of limitations. I was speaking for the the concept of data safety. Undefined data that is never accessed is not unsafe. A smarter compiler, i.e. one able to understand this, would recognize this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Vec` has special methods for that. `swap_remove`, `remove` (warning, linear complexity), `drain`. For example,

```rust
fn extract() -> Vec<String> {
    let mut data = vec!["aaa".to_string(), "bbb".to_string(), "ccc".to_string()];
    // order does matter
    vec![data.swap_remove(2), data.swap_remove(0)]
}
```

Comment: The problem with `remove` and `drain` is that the indices change. Hence, I cannot pull data out with an arbitrary unordered set of indices without tracking how those indices change. However, this seems to be the best compromise possible in Rust. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have "holes" in a vector. So when you move something out of it, you either change the indices of the remaining elements (using `remove` or `swap_remove`), or replace it with something else.

Why don't you just consume the vector in order and ignore what you don't need? If you need to save some of the elements for later use, you can use `data.iter().filter(...).collect()`. If you really want to avoid copying any strings, you can wrap them in `Rc` so that only pointers are copied.

Comment: Because my use case does not fit that model. I am selecting a few key elements from vectors of thousands of strings.

Comment: "If you really want to avoid copying any strings, you can wrap them in Rc so that only pointers are copied." nope, don't do that, rust move semantic will not reallocate String.

Comment: The OP may not be able to use move though. I think it depends on the context.